# IIS redirects for example.com/promotions

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

i am not able set redirects for example.com/example1 to any target in ISS now.
Can you please help?

Whats work is a simple redirect for example.com to any redirect but for a redirect after the / i please need your help.

I was unfortunately not able to find a working solutions in other articles.

Here is the current .web.config for my exampledomain -> example.com with redirect to google.com

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://google.com{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
                    <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
                        pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://google.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Can anyone please help me to add the correct rules to forward example.com/example1 to i.E. google.com ?

Thank you very much in advance

Best Max

i worked with ^$ parameters but that was no help and i searched lot of articles with no help in my case

Comment: could you try adding this new rule: `<rule name="Redirect specific path" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^example1$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://google.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>`

Comment: Hi Jalpa,
sorry for my late response. Works! :)
Thank you very much!